# Safari web browser do not find strings on a page in the common way

Tags: safari, search

How to switch Safari to a *normal* web page searching instead of finding only whole words?

Ex: there ase some words on a page: hello_world, ask_different. When I search for hello, world, ask, different - i search perfectly. But when I'm trying to search *ello*, *ifferent*, etc. - it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The find banner was set to match the starts of words by default in Safari 5.1:

[image]

This makes it default to Contains:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari FindOnPageMatchesWordStartsOnly -bool false
```

You have to quit and reopen Safari to apply the changes.

Comment: defaults don't work in macOS 10.15. But dropdown is still there.