# Find string anywhere, not only at the beginning of words, in Safari on the iPad

Tags: ios, safari, search, ipados

In Safari on macOS one can choose whether to match a word that `starts with` the string or that `contains` it (see answer to [Safari web browser do not find strings on a page in the common way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88464/safari-web-browser-do-not-find-strings-on-a-page-in-the-common-way)). For example, if `Find on page` is set to `contains`, searching for “os” in this page matches the “os” in “choose”, while if it’s set to `start with` it doesn’t.

Apparently I’m stuck with “starts with” on my iPad, but I would like to match all occurrences, anywhere. So is there a way to search for `contains` in iOS Safari?

Answer (score 2):

edit: As of 25 January 2023, they've fixed it. At least it works on my iPad's iPadOS 16.3, but not on my iPhone 7's iOS 15.7.3. Unless I missed some settings. I'd assume the newer iOS would have also fixed the same problem, but it'd be nice to have some confirmation.

---

<s>Impossible.</s>

I personally consider it a bug. But it could be by design, in any case my impression is they don't plan to fix it. I mean it has been a decade since someone noticed the problem.

It affects the mobile iPadOS/iOS's Safari on iPad and iPhone. Possibly on other devices too.

And people generally don't notice it. There are not many hits on google.

- The thread you linked is for desktop Safari: [Safari web browser do not find strings on a page in the common way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88464/safari-web-browser-do-not-find-strings-on-a-page-in-the-common-way)
- The duplicate question is also for desktop Safari: [safari "find" does not work for partial word](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189084/safari-find-does-not-work-for-partial-word)
- Another one, also for desktop Safari: [Safari: search producing unpredictable results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180741/safari-search-producing-unpredictable-results)
- A few on Apple Support Community. Such as [find text on iPad's Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7040843)
- Reddit - [[iOS] Safari's "Find on Page" doesn't support partial word match?](https://old.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/q69oh8/ios_safaris_find_on_page_doesnt_support_partial/)

No one had a solution.

<s>Thanks for asking. Hopefully someone in charge saw it and can push the engineers to fix it. But this question, and the issue in general don't seem to get much traction.</s>

Comment: This doesn't *really* seem like an answer, i.e. a definitive solution, but more of an extended comment... However, maybe that is because, as you point out, there isn't one...?